# Cakephp Pagination how to use or condition

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, paginator

I am trying to filter recipes using a search in a paginator component. But it only searches in the title column of the recipes table. I want it to also search the body column and tags columns of the recipes table.

In controller

```
$this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
$this->Paginator->settings['limit']=$this->pageLimit;
$this->Paginator->settings['maxLimit']=$this->maxLimit;
$this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->Recipe->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams());
```

when I looked into the `$this->Paginator->settings['conditions']` it looks like this

```
Array
(
    [Recipe.title LIKE] => %chocolate%
)
```

I want to extend the conditions to also look into multiple columns of the recipe table more like `Recipe.title LIKE`, `Recipe.body LIKE` and `Recipe.tags LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom function in your model.

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'filter' => array(
        'type' => 'query',
        'method' => 'orConditions'
    ),
);

public function orConditions($data = array()) {
    $filter = $data['filter'];
    $condition = array(
        'OR' => array(
            $this->alias . '.title LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            $this->alias . '.body LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
            $this->alias . '.body LIKE' => '%' . $filter . '%',
        )
    );
    return $condition;
}
```